# Is there non static function in Elixir?

Tags: static, elixir

I am newbie in Elixir, coming from java background. I saw Elixir's function as static methods in java. So I wonder, is there any non-static method / function in Elixir?

Thank you

Comment: It's not even correct to refer to the functions as "static" because static means there's a class template involved.  Elixir doesn't have classes or objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope - all functions belong to a module. Elixir is not an class-oriented language, so the concept of "instance methods vs. class methods" is not applicable.

Aside from typical named functions which belong to a module, there are anonymous functions, similar to lambdas in Java.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is correct and I upvoted it. The basic building blocks in OOP are objects. On the BEAM (Erlang VM), the basic building blocks are processes. So, the distinction between static/instance methods just doesn't make sense.

However, when thinking about what instance methods do in an object oriented language, there is something that does a similar thing in Elixir.

Instance methods, when contrasted with class methods, are the ones that work with internal object state. Elixir doesn't have classes or objects, but it does have processes. A `GenServer` process instance maintains state and passes it into each callback function. So, when you're looking for something that will have state and functions to modify it or return some piece of it, then you want to reach for a [GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html) in Elixir.

All the functions will still belong to the Module. They aren't a unique type of function, but they do allow you to manipulate the state of a given instance of the process because the state gets passed in as a parameter and returned within the function's result.

In response to the comment by @ibgib, yes, when compared with an object oriented language like Java or C#, you can think of all modules and functions in Elixir/Erlang as being static. This is comparing apples to oranges, but if it helps when learning to think of them that way, I think that's OK. Just realize that there isn't any such thing as instance methods here.

Comment: This is related to the interview with Joe Armstrong (one of the co-creators of Erlang) where he said that Erlang (and nowadays Elixir) was the only OO language in the Alan Kay sense of the word for exactly the reasons you're talking about.

http://www.infoq.com/interviews/johnson-armstrong-oop

Comment: Thanks @CodyPoll I didn't have a link to that handy.

Comment: @CoderDennis I am also new to elixir/erlang, and as such, I _think_ the accepted answer is at best misleading. To explicitly complement your answer, which references a `GenServer` as an example of an instance-like process, would you say that a plain `defmodule` is equivalent to a `static class` with static-only methods?